# How to call one method inside another in same jsp file

Tags: html, jsp, methods

```
void generate_footer(String page,int numpages)
{
   String returnstring =
    "</div>" +
"<nav class = 'navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom'>" +
    "<div class = 'container-fluid'>" +
        "<div class = 'row control_bar'>" +
             generate_control_bar(page,numpages) 
        "</div>" +
        "<div class='row status_bar'>" +
               generate_status_bar()
        "</div>" +
    "</div>"+
"</nav>";
}
```

In this code generate_control_bar(page,numpages) and generate_status_bar() are two functions which returns Strings.
But this doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

After generate_control_bar(page,numpages) you didn't put + for concatenation 
change it to

```
 generate_control_bar(page,numpages) 
        +"</div>"+
```

also

```
generate_status_bar()+
        "</div>" +
```